# Orbeon Form - save PDF and XML in local file share after submit/save

Tags: orbeon

Currently I have got Orbeon to send an email to me with a PDF and an XML attachment. Is there a way to get Orbean to also save the submitted form as PDF and XML files in a local (or remote) file share somewhere for further processing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to save to the filesystem at the moment. But you can use the [`send` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner/actions-form-runner-send) to send XML and or PDF to a service.